# Não consigo digitar um número no input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Estou estudando Javascript, criei um sisteminha de cálculo. Mas quando tento digitar o número no input "Custo mensal", ele não vai. Se eu mudo o Input type para text, ele me dá um resultado após clicar no botão de "NaN". Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```js
function calculadora()
{
    let custo = document.getElementById('input-custo');
    let leitos = document.getElementById('input-leitos');                        

    if (leitos.value <= 50)
    {
      let resultado = Math.round((custo.value - 5000) / custo.value * 100) + '%';
      console.log(resultado)
      document.getElementById('resultado').setAttribute("value", resultado);
    }

    else if (leitos.value >= 51 && leitos.value <= 150)
    {
      let resultado = Math.round((custo.value - 7500) / custo.value * 100) + '%';
      console.log(resultado)
      document.getElementById('resultado').setAttribute("value", resultado);
    }

    else if (leitos.value >= 151)
    {
      let resultado = Math.round((custo.value - 10000) / custo.value * 100) + '%';
      console.log(resultado)
      document.getElementById('resultado').setAttribute("value", resultado);
    }     
  }

  function formatarMoeda() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('input-custo');
  var valor = elemento.value;

  valor = valor + '';
  valor = parseInt(valor.replace(/[\D]+/g,''));
  valor = valor + '';
  valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

  if (valor.length > 6) {
    valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
  }

  elemento.value = valor;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .calculadora{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7f4f9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 340px;
    line-height: 30px;

  }
  .perguntas{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #252425;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .espaço{
    height: 15px;
  }

  .botao{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ed2647;
    border: none;
    width: 210px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }

  .botao:hover{
    background-color: #c62246;
  }

  #resultado{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 110px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ed2647;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
  }

  #input-custo{
    background-color: white;
    width: 315px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #54546b;
    margin: 8px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #252425;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 46px;
  }
  #input-leitos{
    background-color: white;
    width: 315px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #54546b;
    margin: 8px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #252425;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 46px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 360px; height: 320px;">
  <div class="calculadora">
    <table>
    <tr><td class="perguntas" style="width: 360px;">Qual é o custo mensal total com<br> cardiologistas em seu hospital?</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="number" id="input-custo" onkeyup="formatarMoeda();" /></td></tr>

    <tr><td class="perguntas" style="width: 360px;">Quantos leitos há em seu hospital?</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="number" id="input-leitos"></td></tr>

    <tr class="espaço"></tr></table>

    <table>
    <tr> <td><button onclick="javascript:calculadora()" class="botao">Economize até*</button></td>
         <td><input id="resultado" readonly></input></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: olá Guilherme, `<input id="resultado" readonly></input>` isso não está certo, a tag `input` não é fechanda como `div` por exemplo, veja mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input... eu editei a pergunta para adicionar o código no snippet e me parece funcionar

Comment: Caro @RicardoPontual, muito obrigado pela rápida resposta! Mas quando digito no primeiro campo um número, ele não deixa. Sabe me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: mas eu consigo digitar: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2659/s0C9wv.png

Comment: @RicardoPontual tenta colocar número maior que duas casas decimais. Por exemplo: 25000 (vinte cinco mil)

Comment: sugiro fazer um debug e ver como está o resultado da variável "result" e ver o que acontece, pq depois está substituindo o valor do campo... valide se o math e formatação estão corretos

Comment: Ele me dá: "the specified value cannot be parsed or is out of range"

Comment: Se o campo é numérico (type="number") ele só vai aceitar número, então formatação não vai rolar, nesse campo... vc pode usar atributo pattern no campo pra aceitar formatações específicas, ex: 'pattern="([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})" `

Comment: ao pegar o valor do html o js pasa para string... então nessa comparação (leitos.value <= 50)... da um aviso que não és um numero...todos os que pegou vai dar NaN... pq js recebe do html literais pode converter aos demais Number(leitos.value)

Comment: tente da seguinte forma, nas primeiras variaveis custo e leitos, converte as para Number  Number(document.getElementById('input-custo').value); remova os value aos demais..e no HTML onde a onclick="javascript:calculadora()" apenas deixe onclick="calculadora()".....abaixo antes do fechamento do body ponha a tag  <script src="teu_script.js"></script>... e ve se ajudou??

Answer (score -1):

Fizemos uns testes aqui e chegamos nessa melhor solução, verifique se encaixa na sua ideia:

```
 function formatarMoeda(event) {
  const valorAtual = event.target.value
  if(isNaN(event.key)){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(0, -1)
    return
  }
  var valor = valorAtual;

  valor = valor.replace('R$', '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim();
  valor = Number(valor)/100;

  valor = valor.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
  event.target.value = valor
}
```

No input ficou assim:

```
<input type="text" id="input-custo" onkeyup="formatarMoeda(event);" />
```

Fiz uns testes aqui e consegui converter o valor do input de custo para número dessa forma:

```
let inputCusto = document.getElementById('input-custo');
const valorCusto = Number(inputCusto.value.replace('R$', '').replace('.', '').replace(',','.'));
```

Um outro problema que encontramos foi que na função calculadora você estava comparando se o leitos.value é menor que determinado número, porém o valor de retorno de leitos.value é uma string, para você fazer essa comparação você deve transformá-lo em número, pode-se fazer isso de duas formas, colocando o sinal de + na frente ou usando o método Number, conforme abaixo:

```
+leitos.value
```

ou

```
Number(leitos.value)
```